# Conditionals don't work in while loops in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I tried to run this loop in Eclipse:

```
String password1= "Victor";
String password2 = "Kevin";
String password;
password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the password.");
while (!password.equals(password1) || !password.equals(password2)) {
    password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Incorrect Password.");
}
```

Basically, I want the while loop to re-execute if the password is not *Victor* or *Kevin*, and when it is, it will end. I keep getting the *"Incorrect Password"* prompt, though, even when I enter Victor or Kevin. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the statement:

```
while (!password.equals(password1) || !password.equals(password2))
```

is always true;

Try changing the pipes for ampersands.

```
while (!password.equals(password1) && !password.equals(password2))
```